# Using switch statement to determine what the user input is

Tags: c#

So I am trying to write a program to input a string value from a user. I am trying to use a switch to determine what has been pressed between "a" and "b". I keep getting the following error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'bool'.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string a = " You pressed a";
        const string b = " You pressed b";

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        switch(input)
        {
            case a:
                ShowData(a);

                break;

            case b:
                ShowData(b);
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine(" You did not type a or b");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
        }
    }

     static void ShowData(string a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ShowData);
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: I think you want `Console.WriteLine(a);` in your `ShowData` method.

Comment: I tried that first, there were more errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with these corrections:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string a = " You pressed a";
            const string b = " You pressed b";

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "a": // correction 1
                    ShowData(a);
                    break;

                case "b": // correction 2
                    ShowData(b);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(" You did not type a or b");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void ShowData(string a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a); // correction 3
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tested out the code and it worked, thanks
I also saw where my mistake was.

Comment: Good. Actually we could also type `case 'a'` and `case 'b'`, because characters in C# are surrounded by `'` while strings by `"`, but anyway it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting seems to be because you are trying to write the ShowData method,

```
static void ShowData(string a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ShowData);
    }
```

should probably be:

```
static void ShowData(string a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
```

I would say that you don't need the ShowData method at all, since you might as well write a directly in your switch, but that's up to you.

This will get rid of the error, but I was still only getting the result "You did not type a or b". This is because your cases are not correct. Since you are looking for the string a, your case should be

```
case "a":
```

instead of

```
case a:
```

Changing this will give the desired behaviour. Here's the final code that I ended up with:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string a = " You pressed a";
        const string b = " You pressed b";

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (input)
        {
            case "a":   //Case changed to "a" instead of a
                ShowData(a);        //Here, we could use Console.writeLine(a) directly if we wanted.
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            case "b":   //Case changed to "b" instead of b
                ShowData(b);    //Here, we could use Console.writeLine(b) directly if we wanted.
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine(" You did not type a or b");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
        }
    }

    static void ShowData(string a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);   //Changed from ShowData to a
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing ShowData to the Console. I think you meant to write `Console.WriteLine(a);` Instead of `Console.WriteLine(ShowData);`